# Is a given key a member of a binary tree - probabilistic answer

Tags: binary-search-tree, probability, theory

The Problem:

Given a BST with `N` nodes, with a domain of cardinality `D` (domain being the possible values for the node keys).
Given a key that is in the domain but may or may not be a member of the BST.
At the start, our confidence that the node is in the tree should be 1/D, but as we go deeper into the tree both D and N are split approximately in half. That would suggest that our confidence that our key is a member of the tree should remain constant until we hit the bottom or discover the key. However, I'm not sure if that reasoning is complete, since it seems more like we are choosing N nodes from D.

I was thinking something along the lines of [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20y%3D(C((10000%2F2%5Ex),1))%2F(C((10000%2F2%5Ex),(128%2F2%5Ex))),%20x%20from%205.5%20to%207), but the reasoning here still doesn't seem complete. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Apriori, the probability that your key in is the tree is N/D.

Without loss of generality, let assume that the node's value range is [1..D].

When you walk down the tree, either:

- The current node matches your key, hence P = 1
- The current node has value C which is larger than your key, you go left, but you don't know how many items are in the left sub-tree. Now you can make one of these assumptions:

  - The tree is balanced. The range in the subtree is [1..C-1], and there are (D-1)/2 nodes in the subtree. Hence, P = ((D-1)/2)/(C-1)
  - The tree is not balanced. The range in the subtree is [1..C-1], and the maximum likelihood estimation for the number of nodes in the subtree is N * (C-1)/D. Hence, P = (N*(C-1)/D)/(C-1) = N/D. (no change)
  - If you know more about how the tree was constructed - you can make a better MLE for the number of nodes in the subtree.
- The current node has value C which is smaller than your key, you go right, but you don't know how many items are in the right sub-tree.

  - ...